# Checking the value returned from ajax request in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert

Hi I have ajax function which will send a request to a PHP file and I want to filter the result returned by the PHP file and want to show an alert boz if the request gives an empty result. Here is my code:

```
function check_invoice(){
        var invno    = this.val();
        var $row     = $(this).closest("tr");
        var vendor   = $row.find('.sub_vendor').val();
        var product  = $row.find('.product').val();
        $.get("../model/check_product_with_invoice_number.php", { invno : invno, product : product, vendor : vendor}, function(result){ 
    if(result == ""){
    alert("Value does Not exist");
}
        });

}
```

Comment: so what is the problem... did you try to alert the value of `resutl` like `alert(result)`

Comment: its not giving any respons

Comment: @user2274075 have you checked the request and response in console tab?

Comment: yup i did but the console is not showing that any request is being sent